# Prevent user from selecting text within an iframe

Tags: css, iframe, css-position

I'm trying to prevent users from selecting text from pdf files shown into an iframe. For this, I've taken a look on `css` properties `position: relative` and `position: absolute`. With that, I'd be able to overlap my iframe with a div, preventing the user from selecting text from my iframe (since he'll be clicking on the overlapping div). This is what I've done so far:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; min-width: 330px; height: 545px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"> 
    <div id="divOverlapIframe" style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; border: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></div>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="MY_PDF_SOURCE" style="height:100%; width:100%; border: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I can see that my div is really overlapping my iframe, but it's not preventing the user from selecting text. What am I missing here?

Comment: first question does iframe contain any external website ??

Comment: Even if you do manage what you're tyring, what stops the user from removing the element using Inspector? It's like trying to prevent users from viewing the source code by preventing right click.

Comment: I would argue  that a standard user wouldn't know where to begin with pulling up the dev inspector muchless where to dig.

Comment: I know that there another tons of ways that the user could retrieve the text. If it's visible, then it's copyable, but preventing this one would be a great feature.

Answer (score 3):

If that's all the CSS you're working with, you might need to slap a z-index on the "overlay" div.

```
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This way I'm not able to copy text but I'm also not able to scroll. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you get a solution for the scrolling?